# ANTLR4: grammar for arithmetic expression - division by zero check, keywords check

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, antlr4

i need help with this grammar for arithmetic expressions.

I would like to notify user with some error message if he tries to divide by zero or if he use some [VHDL keywords](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/reserved.html) (target language) as a variable name.

But i am new to ANTLR and i cant figure out how to extend this grammar:

```
grammar arithmetic;

@header {
    package generated;
}

stat
    :   Left = VARIABLE Op = ASSIGMENT Right = expr     # Assigment
    ;

expr
    :   '('   Exp = expr ')'                            # Parens
    |   MINUS Exp = expr                                # UnaryMinus
    |   Left = expr Op = (TIMES | DIV)  Right = expr    # MulDiv
    |   Left = expr Op = (PLUS  | MINUS) Right = expr   # AddSub
    |   (VARIABLE | CONSTANT)                           # Element
    ;

ASSIGMENT   :   '=' ;
PLUS        :   '+' ;
MINUS       :   '-' ;
TIMES       :   '*' ;
DIV         :   '/' ;
LPAREN      :   '(' ;
RPAREN      :   ')' ;


VARIABLE    :   (LETTER+|DIGIT+|'_')+   ;
CONSTANT    :   INTEGER                 ;

INTEGER     :   DIGIT+                  ;


LETTER      :   ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z') ;
DIGIT       :   ('0' .. '9')    ;

WS          :   [ \r\n\t] + -> skip ;
```

Comment: Division by zero occurs at runtime, not at compile time. The ANTLR system already distinguishes between keywords and identifiers. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well I am compiling expression into VHDL code. So i need to get rid of VHDL keywords like - "abs", "access", "after", "alias", "all", "and", "architecture", "array", "assert", "attribute", "begin", "block", "body" etc. Keywords above were just example, I will edit the question thnx.

Answer (score 1):

I found numerous small problems which I have corrected in the grammar below.

- No EOF marker
- Could only run one statement so extended it to `program`
- The @header thing causes java grungui to not run
- `_` is a valid variable name, probably not what you want.
- '5' is a valid left-hand-side of assignment.  So `5=6` is a valid assignment statement, again, probably not what you want.

  ```
  grammar Arithmetic;
  program : stat+ EOF;
  stat
  :   Left = VARIABLE Op = ASSIGMENT Right = expr     # Assigment
  ;

  expr
  :   '('   Exp = expr ')'                            # Parens
  |   MINUS Exp = expr                                # UnaryMinus
  |   Left = expr Op = (TIMES | DIV)  Right = expr    # MulDiv
  |   Left = expr Op = (PLUS  | MINUS) Right = expr   # AddSub
  |   (VARIABLE | CONSTANT)                           # Element
  ;

  ASSIGMENT   :   '=' ;
  PLUS        :   '+' ;
  MINUS       :   '-' ;
  TIMES       :   '*' ;
  DIV         :   '/' ;
  LPAREN      :   '(' ;
  RPAREN      :   ')' ;
  VARIABLE    :   LETTER+(LETTER|DIGIT|'_')*   ;
  CONSTANT    :   INTEGER                 ;
  INTEGER     :   DIGIT+                  ;
  LETTER      :   ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z') ;
  DIGIT       :   ('0' .. '9')    ;
  WS          :   [ \r\n\t] + -> skip ;
  ```

Now that corrects a lot of lexing and "good form" issues.  The next question is what to do about, for example, division by zero.

The grammar is **not the place** to enforce such rules.  For example, 3/0 is a perfectly legal mathematical expression.  It just so happens to evaluate to infinity, and is therefore to be guarded against in a program.  Likewise, you should handle special cases like this **in your code.**  As you are implementing your visitor or listener pattern when the right-hand-side of the #MulDiv context is equal to zero, you should intervene at that point.  The grammar is no place for trying to implement such sophisticated semantic and context-sensitive rules.

As to how to program an `if` statement, I'll give you a peek at they way I implement them:

```
    public override MuValue VisitIfstmt(LISBASICParser.IfstmtContext context)
    {
        LISBASICParser.Condition_blockContext[] conditions = context.condition_block();
        bool evaluatedBlock = false;
        foreach (LISBASICParser.Condition_blockContext condition in conditions)
        {
            MuValue evaluated = Visit(condition.expr());
            if (evaluated.AsBoolean())
            {
                evaluatedBlock = true;
                Visit(condition.stmt_block());
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!evaluatedBlock && context.stmt_block() != null)
        {
            Visit(context.stmt_block());
        }
        return MuValue.Void;
    }
```

Granted, this probably doesn't make much sense out of context, but rest assured it works.  To see this in its full context, please visit [Bart Kiers](https://github.com/bkiers/Mu) for an excellent example of grammar and implementation .

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am reading arithmetic expression from textfield from GUI, that is why i didn not use EOF. I need to translate single expression into VHDL code. I wanted to separate grammar from ANTLR generated classes so i used header to generate it to different package. I do not know what grungui is, my javafx app seems to work without it. You were right with _ and 5=6. I dont want that to happen, thank you.

Comment: @Samuel  To handle keywords as specific tokens, you can simply follow the advice from the expert [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419707/antlr4-tokenizing-a-huge-set-of-keywords) from Sam Harwell.